# Hide database from user while allowing user to query it

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I was hoping someone could help me with a mySQL / phpMyAdmin problem. (I don't even know if it is possible...)

Here is the problem:
I have 2 databases: DB1 and DB2
I have a user DB1user. This user has full access to DB1 and has select access to specific tables in DB2.
I was hoping that there was a way to hide DB2 from the user. I.e. when user types in 'SHOW DATABASES;', I would like that user to see only DB1. However, when user types in 'SELECT * FROM DB2.TABLE1;', he should see results of his query.

Is this possible? Doable?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the user has select access to DB2 and the privileges are setup correctly, what's the harm in letting the user see DB2? They can only access/modify what they have permissions for.

Comment: That's true. In my case, the database that user has restricted access to is _phpmyadmin_ which is a housekeeping database and I don't necessarily want the user to know of its existence as I am not quite sure what this housekeeping database really stores...

Comment: I think there are no answer to your answer as you wish! The best to do is separate databases in virtual hosts.. each client in your own place. PhpMyAdmin is not the best tool to manage this type os problem, otherwise you have mysql command line, I think is much better to archieve what you want!

Answer (score 0):

These two queries will restrict a user to a single database, so that the user can only see, update, and delete tables from that single database:

Replace USER with the MySQL username

Replace USERDATABASE with the single MySQL database you wish the user to have access to.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES,GRANT OPTION from USER; 

GRANT ALL ON USERDATABASE.* TO 'USER';
```

Comment: But that would limit user's access only to his database... phpMyAdmin has a new database called _phpmyadmin_ which contains some housekeeping information and other phpMyAdmin-related things. Queries against that database happen only when user is logged in via phpMyAdmin interface. User should not even be aware of this database and therefore should not see it in the list of database he has access to. That being said however, if user does know about _phpmyadmin_ he should be able to run queries against it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Privileges page in phpMyAdmin where you can create users and restrict their access to specific databases as well as operations?

Comment: yes. That is what I have right now. User has full access to his db and has select access to phpmyadmin. In the databases section (on the left), I see 3 databases visible: DB1, information_schema, and phmyadmin. I want to see only BD1 there while retaining user's access to phpmyadmin.